# Why this method runs before the other method finishes?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am kinda new to Android programming. I am building a simple application and I have a "follow-unfollow" concept on it. What I simply want is, if the current user follows the user he/she is exploring, I want him/her to see "unfollow" button. If not following, there should be a "follow" button. On my UserProfileActivity class I have a method called onPrepareOptionsMenu() and inside this method I can set the buttons.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem follow = menu.findItem(R.id.action_follow);
    MenuItem unfollow = menu.findItem(R.id.action_unfollow);
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if(isFollowing(bundle.getString("userid")) == true){
        follow.setVisible(false);
        unfollow.setVisible(true);
    }
    else{
        follow.setVisible(true);
        unfollow.setVisible(false);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Also, I have another method called isFollowing() and it returns a boolean "true" if current user follows the other user, it returns "false" if not. It is the simplest way that I have thought to solve this issue.

```
    public boolean isFollowing(String userID){
    isFollowingResult = false;

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    final DatabaseReference followingData = databaseReference.child("followingData");

    followingData.child(currentUser.getUid()).child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                isFollowingResult = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return isFollowingResult;
}
```

When I run this, and when I click on a user's profile onPrepareOptionsMenu() method is called and inside it isFollowing() method is called. The problem is, it does not wait for the isFollowing() method to run and finish running and it immediately sees it as "false" and always shows "follow" button. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your listener is asynchronous, meaning that it will be executed in other thread, so it happens after the method isFollowing is finished.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Can you suggest something to make it synchronous, or is it possible to make it that way?

Comment: Firebase eventlisteners cant be executed immediatelly, also, if it make network operations it would make your app ineresponsible. You have to make your method returns void and inside the onDataChange of the listener you fire a method that continues the execution from where you wanted the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `follow` and `unfollow` the fields of the class. Then change their visibility in `onDataChange(DataSnapshot)` method.

Comment: Actually I have thought about this in the very beginning, but then I thought it would not be a good way to solve it (I did not actually tried by the way), because this is a problem I face at many points in the application. So in order to have a cleaner code I do not want to solve it like this.

Comment: You can move all the code in `isFollowing` method to `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. This way you'll not have to change the local variables to fields.

Comment: By the way I tried it a few minutes ago, it did not work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting the correct result from Firebase? Have you tried to log the result in logcat? Just in case.

Comment: Yes, result is correct. On debug mode i checked it and it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with the code.

Firstly, your `isFollowing()` function is setting up the listener, on the data field, but it'll only get called when the data changes. In this case, you may only want to read the data once:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once

Secondly, the use of a listener implies asynchronicity. Meaning, you'll need to wait until you get the callback later in order to get the value you want.

The ideal solution in order to maintain responsiveness of your app is to maintain a local "copy" of the value in your database with a listener that constantly updates that value. That way, you can query the state of your variable quickly (since it's stored/replicated locally) and still be up to date with your database (with the listener).

This will also prevent each "read" from going all the way to the service and back and also remove the need for your UI to wait to render correctly (accurately).

Comment: you mean i should use something like sqlite?

Comment: Actually, re-reading the setup of your project, you should always query the database (it'd be unreasonable to copy the entire DB into your App) for the state, but add "loading" views to your app until you get the callbacks.